# Playwright Comboboxes

Tags: combobox, playwright

How do I loop through all the options in a combobox using Playwright?

There is no list of options and the values are dynamically generated and at the moment this is what codegen has given me to firstly open the dropdown and then select one of the options:

await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Open' }).first().click();

await page.getByRole('option', { name: 'Option Value 1' }).click();

Codegen only gives me the different options available in the combobox dropdown by name but I need to dynamically step through each option and select it.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do that by getting all inner texts of the combo and then enumerate over that, see below:

```
const combo = await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Open' });
const comboOptions = combo.locator(`option`);

const comboOptions = await comboOptions.allInnerTexts();
const optionsCount = comboOptions.length;

for (let i = 0; i < optionsCount; i++) {
  await combo.selectOption({ label: comboOptions[i] });
}
```

Please upvote and mark as answered if this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but it doesn't seem to populate the constants created.

When I hover over the down arrow of the dropdown box it reflects the text 'Open' but only once clicking on it does values get populated in the combo box.

I've resorted to just hard coding the values in to an array and looping through them which works but is not ideal because if those values change at any stage I will have to update my code again.

Comment: @AndreSteenkamp could you post the html code and your test please?